# Make buffer read-only on a per-file basis

Tags: major-mode, read-only-mode

I know I can set something like `-*- mode: read-only-mode -*-` inside a commentary and Emacs will open the corresponding file as read-only. My problem is that I still want to read files that include such a line with the `org-mode` major mode; Emacs opens these files in `fundamental-mode`.

How can I tell Emacs to open a file as read-only and still make it use the correct major mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`read-only-mode` is a *minor* mode, and should not be set that way.

It's true that using `mode:` with minor modes used to work. I'm not sure offhand if it *still* does, but it's definitely deprecated (and if it's clobbering `org-mode`, then maybe it no longer works at all).

Only use `mode:` to set the major mode, and use `eval:` to enable minor modes:

You can probably use either of these:

```
-*- eval: (read-only-mode 1) -*-
-*- buffer-read-only: t -*-
```

Comment: Using `mode:` with minor modes still works. I use it myself, typically listing a major mode first and then a minor one (like `outline-minor`) afterwards. But I see now that the manual says not to do that, so I guess I shall have to change this practice. Probably with a hook rather than an `eval`.

Answer (score 6):

The normal way would be to make the file read-only in your operating system. With the file open, run [`M-x set-file-modes RET`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-File-Ops.html#index-set_002dfile_002dmodes-1208) (or its alias `chmod`), press <kbd>down</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> to enter the name of the current file, and enter `a=r` (for “all becomes read” — see [file permissions](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#File-permissions) for details). You can also do this from Dired or any other file manager.

Alternatively, if you want the file to be read-only in Emacs but writable in other applications, set the file variable [`buffer-read-only`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Buffer.html#index-buffer_002dread_002donly-1313) to `t`.

```
-*- buffer-read-only: t -*-
```